# Get the variable name of current class

Tags: c#

I need help with my small program. I would like for the program to get the variable name of the class that the method is running in. Something like this:

```cs
class Program()
{
   static void Main()
   {
      Foo somethingForTest = new Foo(); //variable name = [somethingForTest] 
      Console.WriteLine(somethingForTest.Name); //OUTPUT
   }
}


class Foo
{
    public string Name;
    Foo()
    {
        this.Name = nameof(this); //Saving the variable name of this instance 
    }
}
```

The output should be:
`SomethingForTest`

The problem is that when I do this: `nameof(this)`

The compiler says that `this` expression doesn't have a name

Thanks for any tips.

Comment: What would be the point of that?

Comment: Why not `var foo = new Foo() { Name = nameof(foo) };`?

Comment: @Justin in any case that would be `{ Name = "somethingForTest" }`

Comment: @Justin I want it to be automatic. I'm trying to make a framework of sort and want the variable name to be used for the Name parameter when user doesn't specify differently.

Comment: If you hard code it as a string, it will be just as automatic as if you manage to do it some other way. Variable names are hard-coded anyway, so you're not losing any dynamic behaviour. Don't overcomplicate it, just use a string.